# How is the magnetic field strength in the centre of a solenoid derived?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

I understand that for a straight wire the strength of the magnetic field is equal to $B=\frac{I}{2x}$. with x being the distance from the wire.             (1)

I was wondering how this is mathematically derived to equal the equation for magnetic field strength at the centre of a solenoid: $B=\frac{NI}{L}$ with L being the length of the solenoid.           (2)

I also know that $B=\frac{NIr^2}{2(x^2+r^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$ is an intermediary setp, but I am unable to see the steps linking (1 --> 2).

If someone could outline the mathematical procedure that would be a great help.
Thanks!